# Как задать переменную окружения PATH?

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь сделать сборку проекта. Здесь не суть какого. Инструмент для сборки выдает ошибку:

```
sh.CommandNotFound(k), name 'ndk_build' is not define
```

Заглянув в исходники туда, где возникает ошибка, вижу код:

```
sh.ndk_build(*args, **kvargs)
```

Становится понятно, что модуль sh (вызов bash команд как функций из Python) пытается выполнить bash команду ***ndk_build***, которую почему-то не находит. ***ndk_build*** - это bash скрипт из CrystaxNDK, запускающий сборку (CrystaxNDK установлен). Пытался сделать так:

```
export ndk_build="path_to_ndk_build"
```

Получаю ошибку, все в том же месте, что, мол, теперь ***ndk_build*** это строка, а не функция.

Как победить эту область видимости, если так можно сказать?

Comment: Добавьте метку того инструмента ("Инструмент для сборки...") :)

Comment: Что за метка, куда добавить?

Comment: Метка это под вопросом, у вас сейчас стоит <tag:python>. Просто, вопрос не к самому питона, а к инструменту -- сборщику, поэтому чтобы повысить шанс получить ответ это важно указать

Comment: Да, нет, инструмент совсем не при чем. Это не работает только на виртуальной машине. На рабочей ОС все прекрасно находится. Почему-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если требуется установить переменную окружения, можно воспольозваться модулем `os`:

```
os.environ["ndk_build"] = "path_to_ndk_build"
```

В случае модификации `PATH`, которая вряд ли пуста, лучше так:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + new_path
```

Как понимаю, эквивалентно можно записать

```
os.path.join(new_path)
```